# Decimal part of non-integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The reciprocal of p's non-integer decimal  part  equals $p+1$ where $p >0 $. Can it be greater than $\sqrt{2}$?

If we check the answer, then we can write,

$$\sqrt{2} = 1.414213...$$ and then  the  reciprocal of the decimal of the non-integer will be  $$\frac{1}{0.414213...} = 2.414213...$$

Therefore  the statement satisfies  for $1 + \sqrt{2} = 2.414213$ Is there any other possibility that other noninteger can satisfy the condition? How can we evaluate that?

Comment: Consider providing the compete question....

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes. I have edited the question.

Comment: It should be $0.414213$ and not $0.0414213$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every natural number $n$ there is one solution $p_n$ between $n$ and $n+1$, and it is given by the equation
$$
\frac{1}{p_n-n} = p_n+1
$$
which can be rewritten as
$$
p_n^2 - (n-1)p_n - n-1 = 0
$$
This equation has two solutions, but we want the positive one, which is
$$
p_n = \frac{n-1 + \sqrt{(n-1)^2 + 4(n+1)}}{2} = \frac{n-1+\sqrt{(n+1)^2 + 4}}{2}
$$
for $n = 0$, this gives $p_0 = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$, also known as $\phi - 1$ where $\phi = 1.618\ldots$ is the golden ratio. For $n = 1$ we get $p_1 = \sqrt{2}$ as you noted, and from there you can just keep making more of them.

Comment: How would I know that  you have constructed the formula for non-integer no only?

Comment: @RayanAhmed Because $\frac{n-1+\sqrt{(n+1)^2 + 4}}{2}$ is the average of $(n-1)$ and $\sqrt{(n+1)^2 + 4}$, where we can see that the latter is a little bit bigger than $(n+1)$. Therefore the result has to be strictly bigger than $n$, being the average of $(n-1)$ and $(n+1+\text{ a little more})$. If the result were to be $(n+1)$ or greater, then we would need $\sqrt{(n+1)^2 + 4}$ to be $(n+3)$ or greater, which cannot happen (the $\!{}+4$ in there isn't big enough). This means that we get a $p_n$ with $n<p_n<n+1$, which means it is _not_ an integer.